# Report Viewer DLL loading issue in Azure function

Tags: function, azure, reportviewer

I have added following DLL and set local copy true

Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll 10.0.0.0

Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll 10.0.0.0

Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll 10.0.0.0

When I browse application folder throws Azure Kudu, I can see above DLL in the bin folder.

I am always getting this error in the production but It works well locally.

'Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Answer (score 0):

When you host your ASP.NET application on-premises, the ReportViewer assemblies are usually installed directly in the global assembly cache (GAC) of the IIS server during Visual Studio installation, and can be accessed directly by the application. However, when you host your ASP.NET application in the cloud, Microsoft **Azure does not allow anything to be installed into the GAC.**

> I am always getting this error in the production but It works well locally.

It seems that your ReportViewer assemblies are available locally. So, you could refer to the suggestions as below:

First, make sure your Azure function is running on **app service plan**.

Secondly, **download** Microsoft Report Viewer 2012 Runtime redistributable package.

Then, create folder in the project and copy the associated resource assembly files there and set the property "Copy to Output Directory" to **"Copy always"**.

For more detail, you could refer to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sqlclassic/virtual-machines-windows-classic-sql-server-reportviewer).